# Unix utility to finish this term frequency counter pipeline

Tags: unix, scripting, awk

Right now I have to write a little script that takes a directory of documents(the example given is each chapter in Revelation) and turn them into a term frequency document.  So far, I have:

```
foreach file ($1/*)
   java Stemmer $file | tr " " "\n" | tr "[:punct:]" "\n" | egrep -v ^$ | sort |
   egrep -x -v -f stopwords
```

So, right now it goes through each file, running it through a Porter stemmer, getting rid of all punctuation and extra spaces and black lines, sorting them, and eliminating all of the stopwords.  My question is, what could I possibly do to make it so the output goes from

```
apple  
boy  
boy  
cat  
cat  
cat  
dog
```

to

```
apple 1  
boy 2  
cat 3  
dog 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is to use `uniq -c` as your list in presorted however the output isn't in the exact formatted you want:

```
$ uniq -c file
       1 apple
       2 boy
       3 cat
       1 dog
```

This `awk` script give the exacted formated wanted:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(k in a) print k, a[k]}' file
apple 1
cat 3
boy 2
dog 1
```

Note: you should replace the pipeline with a single `awk` script however.

Comment: How would I redirect the files, either in the awk or the uniq example, so that the output would be, essentially, $file.tf (example.txt.tf)?

Comment: It you want to store the results in a file then you want the redirection operator `>` so `... | uniq -c > example.txt.ft` where `...` is your pipeline, this will redirect the output into the given file.

Comment: No, I know that, but I can't figure out how to have it go to $file.ft.  Because >$file.ft throws an error.

Comment: If the value of `$file` is `example.txt` and you want to redirect to `example.txt.ft` then you want `> "${file}.ft"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' input|sort
```

will output exactly same as your expected. (with your example), keep the words alpha-beta sorted.